# Need guidance on ASPX website automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, automation

NET ASPX Timesheet website automation, where i have to detect whenever a submit button is pressed by the user and send email automatically.

Unfortunately we dont have access to any website code. Just the website which we can use in internet Explorer.

How to detect the button press? how should i proceed? Do i need to write some custom browser plugin?

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense, you're asking how to get access to a websites sessions without having access to the website code or server. I don't think this can be done, in fact I would be really surprised if it can.

Think about the privacy issues.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure on how to proceed either, but looks like Automation Testing is the way to proceed. Some of my friends suggested QTP and Firefox Selenium.